# JQuery Find with string variables

Tags: jquery, traversal

Can I query the DOM with $() using a string variable as a parameter?

i.e.

```
var divContainerID = "divBlock1"; 
$(divContainerID).show();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
var divContainerID = "divBlock1"; 
$('#'+divContainerID).show();
```

if `divContainerID` is an actual id of an element or

```
var divContainerID = "divBlock1"; 
$('.'+divContainerID).show();
```

if it's a class (which I'm kind of assuming it isn't, but I thought I'd give it to you anyway).

Comment: That's what I was missing... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  As long as the string represents a valid query, this should present no problem.

Comment: I love this site... 

Thanks I needed a sanity check on that one.

Comment: @Antilogic, this site is addictive. Be careful how much time you spend here or you may become stuck like the rest of is :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course man, sometimes this is the only way. But, just so you know, the query you have in your example isn't a valid query. Presumably you are querying a class or id...

It would need to be like this:

```
var divContainerID = "#divBlock1"; 
$(divContainerID).show();
```

or:

```
var divContainerID = ".divBlock1"; 
$(divContainerID).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but remember the string will need a

- `#` prefix if it is an id
- `.` prefix if it is a CSS class

Otherwise, it's assumed to be a HTML element